# git alias get cwd

Tags: git

If I define a git alias that executes an external script is there any way to get the original CWD? I know external scripts always execute at the root of the repo so I was just wondering if there was an env variable or something I could use to figure out where I ran my script.

Here is an example alias:

```
git config --global alias.here '!echo pwd `pwd`'

/home/me/repo/folder$ git here
pwd /home/me/repo
```

I'm looking for something that does the following:

```
git config --global alias.here '!echo pwd $OLD_PWD'


/home/me/repo/folder$ git here
pwd /home/me/repo/folder
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the manual, you should be able to use `GIT_PREFIX`, which will be set with the same prefix as returned by `git rev-parse --show-prefix`. You can append that prefix to the root path.

http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html

Comment: Do you know what version of git that was added in ? Apparently i'm on 1.7.1 which I think is outdated. Might have to manually install the update.

Comment: I had an outdated version of git. Apparently the version on ubuntu 10.10 is pretty old. Use the PPA to update to a newer version.

Comment: For anyone still stuck with Git 1.7.x, `GIT_PREFIX` was first added in Git 1.7.6.