# git aliases operate in the wrong directory

Tags: git, directory

Summary: the current working directory of commands run through git aliases is wrong.

The easiest way to demonstrate this is to have a git alias like so:

```
[alias]
    pwd = !pwd
```

So `git pwd` is just running the bash command `pwd`. One would think that the two commands' outputs would be the same. Now, let's try this out a few times:

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd && git pwd
/home/limpchimp
/home/limpchimp    # great!
$ mkdir foo && cd foo && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/limpchimp/foo/.git/
$ pwd && git pwd
/home/limpchimp/foo
/home/limpchimp/foo  # great!
$ mkdir bar && cd bar
$ pwd && git pwd
/home/limpchimp/foo/bar
/home/limpchimp/foo   # uuhhhhhhhh...?
```

It seems that git is changing the current working directory to be the first parent directory that has a `.git` folder (if one exists). This is very problematic; it's screwing up certain scripts that I've written, which are meant to operate in a specific directory, and making me unable to use certain things as git aliases. Is there a way around this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does running command as git alias gives different results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832799/why-does-running-command-as-git-alias-gives-different-results)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is clearly specified in the documentation as by design along with a workaround if needed.

[Git Config Alias](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

> Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory
>   of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.
>   GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running git rev-parse --show-prefix
>   from the original current directory

Comment: "This is clearly specified..." - if by clearly specified you mean the explanation for non-obvious, surprising and non-intuitive behavior being buried in a manpage that's more than 2500 lines long.

Answer (score 27):

TL;DR: add `cd -- \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\";`  in front of the rest of the alias, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    pwd = !cd -- \"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\"; pwd
```

---

This is a (mis?)feature, but you can work around it with `$GIT_PREFIX` as noted in [this other stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039870/git-alias-get-cwd):

```
#! /bin/sh
# script to do stuff in a git dir
# since we're sometimes run from a git alias we need
# to cd back into $GIT_PREFIX if it's set
[ "$GIT_PREFIX" != "" ] && cd -- "$GIT_PREFIX"
... rest of script ...
```

(As [Tom Hale noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243145/git-aliases-operate-in-the-wrong-directory/26243454?noredirect=1#comment91435590_26243454), one can shorten this using the sh / bash / POSIX-shell feature ${var:-default}, where an unset or empty-string variable value expands to the default given after the colon-dash character pair.  We use the `--` because bash has added *options* to the `cd` command, so for robustness we should handle a case where the prefix variable contains, say, `-e`.  The double quotes are not necessary either: I used them above for symmetry with the `test` command, which the longer version above spells as `[`.)

Comment: Or shorter, for use in an alias: `cd -- "${GIT_PRFIX:-.}`