# How can I restrict git status to regular files in the current directory only?

Tags: git, git-status

I would like to see the status of the current directory. Because there are lots of changes in sub-directories, which I do *not* want to see, the following command doesn't do the trick:

```
git status .
```

Is there any way of getting this kind of report, short of grepping the output of `git status`?

Comment: Very important question: is this needed for human interpretation or for scripting?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate more than 6 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Use `git-status -- <pathspec>...`

The synopsis of the [`git-status` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) tells you that you can filter by paths:

```
git status [<options>...] [--] [<pathspec>...]
```

Therefore, all you have to do is get a list of paths corresponding to the regular (non-directory) files in the current directory, and pass that to `git-status`.

There is one gotcha: because `git status` reports about the *whole* repository if passed an empty `<pathspec>...` argument, you need to check whether the list is empty or not.

### Shell script

Here is a small shell script that does what you want.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-status-dot
#
# Show the status of non-directory files (if any) in the working directory
#
# To make a Git alias called 'status-dot' out of this script,
# put the latter on your search path, make it executable, and run
#
#   git config --global alias.status-dot '! git-status-dot'

# Because GIt aliases are run from the top-level directory of the repo,
# we need to change directory back to $GIT_PREFIX.
[ "$GIT_PREFIX" != "" ] && cd "$GIT_PREFIX"

# List Non-Directory Files in the Current Directory
lsnondirdot=$(ls -ap | grep -v /)

# If "lsnondirdot" is not empty, pass its value to "git status".
if [ -n "$lsnondirdot" ]
then
    git status -- $lsnondirdot
else
    printf "No non-directory files in the working directory\n"
fi

exit $?
```

For more details about why the `GIT_PREFIX` shenanigans are required, see [git aliases operate in the wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243145/git-aliases-operate-in-the-wrong-directory).

The script is available at [Jubobs/git-aliases](https://github.com/Jubobs/git-aliases) on GitHub.

### Make a Git alias out of it

For convenience, you can create a Git alias that calls the script; make sure the script is on your path, though.

```
git config --global alias.statusdot '!sh git-status-dot.sh'
```

### Toy example

Here is a toy example demonstrating how to use the resulting alias and what it does.

```sh
# initialize a repo
$ mkdir testgit
$ cd testgit
$ git init

# create two files
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/foo.txt
$ touch bar.txt

# good old git status reports that subdir/test1.txt is untracked... 
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    bar.txt
    foo/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
# ... whereas our new alias, git status-dot, only cares
# about regular files in the current directory
$ git status-dot
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    bar.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

# and if we delete README.md ...
$ rm README.md
# ... good old git status still bother us about /subdir ...
$ git status
Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
# ... whereas git statusdot doesn't
$ git status-dot
No non-directory files in the working directory
$
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a message if `lsrfdot` is empty; something like `No files in the current directory`. Furthermore it might make sense to use `ls -ap` to include unix style hidden files.

Comment: Nicely done! +1. Zeeker's suggestions seem sensible too.

Comment: @Zeeker Excellent suggestion. I'll do that.

Comment: Small typo in the script (lsrdot), otherwise good solution. A pity that git does not provide this out of the box (seems like a useful feature to me)

Comment: Nice solution. It comprises the ideas, arguments and suggestions that emerged in this page in the other answers and their comments. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there's a more proper way to do this, but you can simply

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 git status
```

Of course, this fails if there's no regular files on the current directory. In that case, you can use the extra ugly version

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 git status nonexistentfile
```

And, no, I'm not going to address the case where you have a file named `nonexistentfile`.

Comment: I get `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.` from this.

Comment: @Trengot you can safely ignore it. I've edited the answer to avoid the warning

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP was after. If I do this I get changes in subdirectories.

Comment: Should use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to avoid escaping issues with some file names.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you're absolutely right, I've added them to the answer

Comment: @Trengot do those subdirectories appear on `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`?

Comment: @goncalopp no. Nothing is returned (I have no files in the root of the repo).

Comment: @Trengot that's the problem then. I've added a "fix".  This is getting uglier by the minute

Comment: Usually I don't add this kind of comments but +1 for "And, no, I'm not going to address the case where you have a file named `nonexistentfile`". That made me laught. Good answer nonetherless.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
git status | grep -v /
```

to filter out any paths that contain a slash (`/`) which means they are in subdirectories.

You will also lose the red/green coloring of the changed paths.

**Update:**

This solution does not display the files that are moved from or to the current directory because the source and destination of a move operation are displayed on the same line in the output. The files that were renamed in the current directory (without being moved between directories) are displayed though.

Comment: That's not the right way to do it. If you don't have any changes in the current directory but you do further down in the file-system hierarchy, the output of `git status` will contain stuff relevant to those changes. You need to filter stuff out *before* calling `git status`.

Comment: @Jubobs, OP wants to ignore changes further down the hierarchy.

Comment: @Trengot I know; that's my point: this command will contain output relevant to changes further down the hierarchy. Grepping the output of an unfiltered `git status` is not satisfactory.

Comment: Notice that the OP is explicitly excluding this solution in his question: `short of grepping the output of git status`. Although it's possibly the simplest...

Comment: @Jubobs `git status` displays the paths of the new/modified/deleted files using relative paths. Everything that is not in the current directory will have at least one slash (`/`) in its relative path, no matter if it's in a subdirectory or in a parent directory (or a different subdirectory of a parent directory). `grep -v /` excludes all the lines that contain at least one `/`. The files in the current directory are not affected. Also the lines where `git` gives hints about what to do next are not affected.

Comment: @axiac You're missing my point... Unfortunately, I can't elaborate in a comment.

Comment: @goncalopp I did not notice that part of the request before.

Comment: @Jubobs the output of my command produces `git` comments and hints that apply to files that are excluded by `grep -v` and doesn't necessarily apply to the files in the current directory. But the list of files is correct.

Comment: @Jubobs do you mean the "Changes not staged for commit" type headings? You can get around this by using `git status -s` (or `git status --porcelain` to guarantee it won't change output in new git versions)

Comment: On a second thought, `grep -v /` will ignore a file that was moved from or to the current directory as the source and destination of the move operation are listed on the same line. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is no...

Unless the files are untracked files, submodules, or ignored files. The full documentation for the [status](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) command mentions nothing about limiting the output to the current directory.

However, you might want to consider using the [stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) command to clean up your working tree. If you stash everything not in your current directory (which requires the `--patch` option to only stash selective parts), then `status` will only show what you didn't stash. However, if you use `stash` multiple times while working, then you should always have a clean working tree and you could avoid this problem to begin with. Each body of work will be packaged up in a separate stash waiting until you are ready to commit it.

Of course, that doesn't help much with your current situation (aside from using (`stash --patch`). Another alternative you might want to try is the [interactive mode](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_interactive_mode) of the `add` command. Then you can go through all the changed files and selectively add the ones you want (`stash --patch` works the same way).

Or, you can use the grep solutions suggested in other answers.